# What is the correct way to handle an element within an element with HTMLAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Say I've got the following piece of HTML

```
<p>Peter Piper picked a pack of <b>pickled</b> peppers</p>
```

And I want to process it with HTML Agility Pack, turning every `p` into a `div` and every `b` into a `strong`.

I know how to process all `p` tags,

```
foreach(var p in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p"))
{
    var p_text = p.innerText;
    // do something with p.innerText;
}
```

and I even how to process the `b` tags within my `p` tags

```
foreach(var p in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p"))
{
    var p_text = p.innerText;
    // do something with p.innerText;

    foreach(var b in p.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "b"))
    {
        // do something with b;
    }
}
```

But that's where I'm stumped. The innerText of the `p` and my collection of `b` nodes are separate. How do I process the `b` tags in such a way as to keep them in the correct position in my 'p' node?

I'm really just trying to understand how to approach this from an architectural standpoint

PS: Apologies if there are mistakes in my code, I'm doing it from memory purely as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
foreach (var p in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p"))
{
    p.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(
           HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<div>" + p.InnerHtml + "</div>"), 
           p);
}

foreach (var b in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//b"))
{
    b.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<strong>" + b.InnerHtml + "</strong>"), 
    b);
}
```

Comment: I really wasn't expecting it to work like that. Seems so obvious now. Thanks!